# Hit the bullseye

Tags: word, visual

This is another puzzle grabbed from a popular Italian magazine. The rules are pretty much the same except that there are more words! While this might look harmlessly easy, unlike my Star of Dice, don't be deceived! It will be a nice mental exercise. Also, there is only one correct order. Multiple associations might be there, at least apparently, but you must choose the ones that will allow you to use up all the words *properly*.

**Objective**

Starting from the word indicated by the arrow (in this case `MASTER`), you must reach the center of the target, progressively associating and eliminating all the words included in it, that can be found in any ring, not necessarily in order, according to the rules below.

**Rules**

1. The word can be an anagram of the previous one.
2. It can be a synonym or an antonym of the previous one.
3. It can be obtained by adding, removing, or replacing a letter in the previous one.
4. It can be associated to the previous one because of a saying (proverb), metaphor, or word association.
5. It can form, together with the previous one, the name of a celebrity, or a place.
6. It can associated to a work of art (book, theater, poetry, etc.), its author, or its title including any genre.

In your answer, you should explain and/or justify each association.

[image]

**Hint**

> `urn` $\rightarrow$ `eternity`

For quick reference, the words in the bullseye, going towards the center, are:

> MASTER sea nee horse wing entirety force driver rhcp plane fore sting keats leaf row bow stream faction poisoned plan genre gowan opposite fraction stage golf attraction gown finger shore software eternity guitar wagon river swing poseidon arrow flea antidote stake ball bee urn prod program theater string fringe green drop knee HAIR

Comment: If possible, please use a **single** spoiler block, it's much easier to read. :D

Comment: Is there any significance to the rings, or is this just a more difficult to read unordered list? Do we have to go from one ring to the next? Can rings spin? I don't understand the purpose of the diagram.

Comment: @IanMacDonald The rings are mostly just presentation (and also to mislead the answerer). They cannot spin, and if they could, it wouldn't change anything. You can move from any ring to any ring (or even stay in the same ring).

Comment: It sounds like we don't have to use all the rules. Is that correct?

Comment: @jstnthms The rules state that the next word can be one of those things, so the rules being used may vary.

Comment: So really what you're asking is for an ordering that includes *all* of the following words starting at MASTER and ending at HAIR according to the rules you've listed: MASTER, FORE, STING, KEATS, LEAF, ROW, SEA, NEE, HORSE, WING, ENTIRETY, FORCE, DRIVER, RHCP, SCHEDULE, STREAM, FACTION, POISONED, PLAN, GENRE, GOWAN, OPPOSITE, FRACTION, STAGE, GOLF, BOW, GOWN, FLEA, FINGER, SHORE, GROUP, ETERNITY, GUITAR, WAGON, ATTRACTION, POSEIDON, ARROW, ANTIDOTE, STAKE, BALL, RIVER, SWING, THEATER, STRING, BEE, URN, PROD, PROGRAM, FRINGE, GREEN, DROP, KNEE, HAIR

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes.

Comment: Some of these rules seem very vague to me.  Anagrams, synonyms, and antonyms seem fine, as well as adding or removing letters, but word association allows for an awful lot of interpretation.  I wouldn't be surprised to see several different "legitimate" answers, based on whatever the poster thinks is a valid word association.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I thought of that, but even if you found an unlikely but possible word association, it would be superseded by another more likely one.

Comment: It seems like Rule 6 could allow for just about anything.  Associating to *any* work of art, author, or title?  I could probably pick almost any two words in this list, and find the title of some work of art that includes them.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain You could, maybe, but I doubt that would allow you to reach a solution. And considering the answers that have been given, that's not going to be a problem.

Comment: Adesso la settimana enigmistica vanta un tentativo di imitazione anche su StackExchange!

Answer (score 8):

Master

> Stream via Anagram
> River via Synonym
> Driver via Added Letter
> Wagon via Association ->Wagon Driver
> Gowan via Anagram
> Gown via Subtracted Letter
> Ball via Association ->Ball Gown
> Golf via Association ->Golf Ball
> Fore via Association -> Yell 'Fore' while playing Golf
> Force via Added Letter
> Attraction via Association -> Electromagnetic Attraction is a Force
> Opposite via Association -> Opposites feel Attraction (Opposites Attract)
> Faction via Association -> Factions imply opposed groups
> Fraction via Added Letter
> Entirety via Antonym
> Eternity via Anogram
> Urn via Association -> 'Eternity' funerary urns
> Keats via Association -> Wrote 'Ode on a Grecian Urn'
> Stake via Anagram
> Stage via Letter Replacement
> Program via Association ->Stage Program
> Software via Association ->Software Program
> Plan via Association ->Software execution Plan
> Plane via Added Letter
> Wing via Association ->Plane Wing
> Swing via Added Letter
> Sting via Changing Letter
> Antidote via Antonym
> Poisoned via Antonym
> Poseidon via Anagram
> Sea via Association -> God of the Sea (and Horses)
> Horse via Association -> Seahorse (these can be inverted for fun and profit)
> Shore via Anagram ->(If above is inverted, Association->She sells sea shells by the Sea Shore)
> Row via Association ->Dinah, Row your boat to Shore
> Bow via Changing Letter
> Arrow via Association ->Bow and Arrow 
> Knee via Association ->Arrow to the Knee
> Nee via Dropped Letter
> Bee via Changing Letter
> Drop via Association -> Bee produces honey Drop
> Prod via Anagram
> Finger via Association ->Prod with Finger
> Fringe via Anagram
> String via Association ->String Fringe
> Guitar via Association ->Guitar String
> RHCP via Association ->Guitar Band
> Flea via Association ->Flea is a member of RHCP
> Leaf via Anagram
> Green via Association ->Leaf Green
> Genre via Anagram
> Theater via Association -> Theater Genres
> Hair via Association ->Hair(Broadway Musical)

And we're at Hair!

Comment: Yes, RHCP is what you think it is. I couldn't fit it otherwise. :D

Comment: You've done huge progress, but there's a word association that doesn't work in your list.

Comment: I think it should go **POSEIDON** $\rightarrow$ **SEA** $\rightarrow$ **HORSE** $\rightarrow$ **SHORE**.

Comment: Theater seems like it doesn't fit with anything

Comment: @MMAdams It does. :P

Comment: Sconibulus, I fixed the bullseye. Replaced something and it seems that in one of all the changes I was doing, I missed one word. Now it has been added. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I feel like I'm very close, but there are a number of words that only seem to connect to one other word, and I can't see any way to connect them to another:

> **OPPOSITE**, **ETERNITY**, **ANTIDOTE**, **URN**, **KNEE** (among others)

Here are the groups I've come up with so far.  Maybe someone else can find the connections I'm missing...

> **MASTER** anagrams to
>  **STREAM** is a synonym of
>  **RIVER** is one letter short of
>  **DRIVER** is a club in
>  **GOLF** is where people often say
>  **FORE** is one letter short of
>  **FORCE** is a synonym of
>  **ATTRACTION** is in a common phrase with
>  **OPPOSITE**
>
>  **ETERNITY** anagrams to
>  **ENTIRETY** is an antonym of
>  **FRACTION** is one letter more than
>  **FACTION** is a synonym of
>  **GENRE** anagrams to
>  **GREEN** describes a
>  **LEAF** anagrams to
>  **FLEA** is a singer in
>  **RHCP** where they play
>  **GUITAR** has a
>  **STRING** which is often rolled into a
>  **BALL** is in a common phrase with
>  **GOWN** is one letter short of
>  **GOWAN** anagrams to
>  **WAGON** is pulled by a
>  **HORSE** anagrams to
>  **SHORE** is in a common phrase with
>  **SEA** is the domain of
>  **POSEIDON** anagrams to
>  **POISONED** is (sort of) an antonym of
>  **ANTIDOTE**
>
>  **URN** is in the title of "Ode to a Grecian Urn" by
>  **KEATS** anagrams to
>  **STAKE** is one letter different from
>  **STAGE** is commonly found in a
>  **THEATER** is usually performed by a
>  **GROUP**
>
>  **WING** is one letter short of
>  **SWING** is one letter different from
>  **STING** is done by a
>  **BEE** is one letter different from
>  **NEE** is one letter short of
>  **KNEE**
>
>  **ARROW** is often paired with a
>  **BOW** is one letter different from
>  **ROW**
>
>  **PROGRAM** is a synonym of
>  **SCHEDULE** is a synonym of
>  **PLAN**
>
>  **DROP** is an anagram of
>  **PROD** is a synonym of
>  **FINGER** is an anagram of
>  **FRINGE** is commonly found in
>  **HAIR**

Comment: I'm fairly sure 'knee' and 'arrow' are linked via the phrase 'took an arrow to the knee'

Comment: I fixed the bullseye. Replaced something and it seems that in one of all the changes I was doing, I missed one word. Now it has been added. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Alenanno It looks like you removed **GROUP** and **SCHEDULE** and added **SOFTWARE** and **PLANE**.  Is that correct?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yes. I have included the text list in the main question and also added a hint for the hardest association. It will be helpful. Sorry again for the mess!

Answer (score 2):

Start:
Master

> 1: Stream an anagram of Master (@Beastly-Gerbil)
> 2: River a synonym of Stream
> 3: Driver is River with a D added
> 4: Golf a Golf Driver is a kind of golf club
> 5:
> Ball, a Golf Ball
> 6:
> Gown, a Ball Gown
> 7:
> Gowan, Gown with an A added
> 8:
> Wagon, an anagram of Gowan
> 9: Horse, a Horse and Wagon
> 10: Shore, an anagram of Horse
> 11: Sea, a Sea shore
> 12: Poseidon, the god of the Sea
> 13: Poisoned, an anagram of Poseidon
> 14: Antidote, a cure for one who is poisoned
> 15: Drop, a drop of Antidote
> 16: Prod, anagram of Drop

Some of the middle is definitely:

> Guitar, String, Sting, Swing, Wing
> Stage, Stake, Keats, Urn
> Faction, Fraction, Entirety, Eternity
> Bee, Nee, Knee
> Leaf, Flea, RHCP
> Force, Fore
> Genre, Green
> Row, Bow, Arrow
> Opposite, Attraction

Not sure of all middle steps but the end could be:

> Finger, what someone uses to Prod
> Fringe, an anagram of Finger
> Hair, Fringe is another word for bangs, which are made of Hair

Comment: I fixed the bullseye. Replaced something and it seems that in one of all the changes I was doing, I missed one word. Now it has been added. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with and I only traverse inwards. Though, I'm not sure if I misused rule #4:

> **1. Master -> Gowan** using #5 (celebrity; "Gowan" is a popular singer/song-writer)
>  **2. Gowan -> Gown** using #3 (removing a letter)
>  **3. Gown -> Ball** using #4 (word association; you wear a "gown" to a "ball" or dance)
>  **4. Ball -> String** using #4 (word association; a "ball" of "string")
>  **5. String -> Fringe** using #4 (word association; decoration of threads or "string" on the edge of clothing is called a "fringe")
>  **6. Fringe -> Hair** using #2 ("fringe" is another word for bangs as in the "hair" covering your forehead)

I also wondered if you could make associations like this:

> **1. Master -> Gowan** using #5 (Gowan is a popular singer/song-writer)
>  **2. Gowan -> Group** using #4 (word association; Gowan is the lead singer of the "group" Styx)
>   **3. Group -> Stake** using #4 (word association; a "stake" is a stick ("Styx"))

Or is that too much of a stretch?

EDIT: Perhaps I misread the puzzle. We have to use every single word?

Comment: Yes, every single word. Of course, the rules seem to allow *any* association possible, but if you're missing words in your list or if some associations are really stretched, I'd suggest revisiting.

Comment: I fixed the bullseye. Replaced something and it seems that in one of all the changes I was doing, I missed one word. Now it has been added. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

First one is

> **MASTER** is an anagram of **STREAM** on the next row

Comment: I fixed the bullseye. Replaced something and it seems that in one of all the changes I was doing, I missed one word. Now it has been added. Sorry for the inconvenience.